# Monary: Aggregation framework, set the allowDiskUse option

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, monary

I am using Monary to connect to my MongoDB.
but I am struggling to figure out where exactly and how to set the allowDiskUse option?

```
client = Monary("ip.address.of.server", 27017 , "username", "password", "dbname")

pipeline = [
        {"$group" : {
            "_id" : {"user":"$subscriber_id",
                 "month": { "$month" : "$timestamp" },
                 "day" : { "$dayOfMonth" : "$timestamp" },
                 "year" : { "$year" : "$timestamp" },
                 "hour" : { "$hour" : "$timestamp" },
                 "category":"$category_name"
                },
            "activities_sum":{"$sum":"$activity_count"}
            }
        }
    ]

with client as m:
    users, years, months, days, hours, categories, activities  = m.aggregate("digicel_exploration",
                "5_min_slots",
                time_aggregation_pipeline,
                ["_id.user", "_id.year", "_id.month", "_id.day", "_id.hour", "_id.category", "activities_sum"],
                ["string:30", "int32", "int32", "int32", "int32", "string:60", "int32"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monary uses the mongoc driver underneath and directly in a way that does not abstract the pymongo driver, which is really the official source that is under MongoDB company maintenance.

As such the implementation has been done in a way that does not allow the necessary "options" to be passed into the `aggregate()` method for things such as "allowDiskUse".

You can see the implementation code [here](https://bitbucket.org/djcbeach/monary/src/5b0fb0c2de0a4f4b32bd79bb593e8cf2f39fe474/monary/cmonary.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#cmonary.c-980), paying attention to the forth and fifth arguments which are hard coded `NULL`:

```c
// Get an aggregation cursor
mcursor = mongoc_collection_aggregate(collection,
                                      MONGOC_QUERY_NONE,
                                      &pl_bson, NULL, NULL);
```

When you compare this to the doccumented signature for `mongoc_collection_aggregate`, then the problem becomes clear:

```c
mongoc_cursor_t *
mongoc_collection_aggregate (mongoc_collection_t       *collection,
                             mongoc_query_flags_t       flags,
                             const bson_t              *pipeline,
                             const bson_t              *options,
                             const mongoc_read_prefs_t *read_prefs)
   BSON_GNUC_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
```

If you need this option in your processing, then you would be better off using [pymongo](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) directly and loading up your [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays manually based on the results.

Alternately, you could take the approach as has already been mentioned in a [reported issue](https://bitbucket.org/djcbeach/monary/issues/14/passing-options-to-aggregate) on the subject, and patch up the source yourself if you are prepared to build yourself:

```c
bson_t opts;
bson_init(&opts);
BSON_APPEND_BOOL (&opts, "allowDiskUse", true);
mcursor = mongoc_collection_aggregate(collection,
                                      MONGOC_QUERY_NONE,
                                      &pl_bson, &opts, NULL);
bson_destroy(&opts);
```

Or even provide a full patch yourself that adds the options signature to the method definition and passes them through correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer, I was hoping to use Monary as it can load directly the results into NumPy arrays. I might then back to pymongo knowing that it will be slower... but I am not ready to patch the source myself :) Cheers